# Importing many rows from sql using specific values

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net, import, datatable

I am writing an application in vb.NET and I am looking for most efficient way to import a lot of data from SQL table.
I have about 10k rows in Excel and I have to match every of these with particular SQL table row (about 100k records). In every row there are three columns, which together identify particular row. I mean that it is not possible for 2 rows to have identical values in all 3 columns and I want to use these as a key to match. I wonder what is the most efficient technique to do that, because I think that doing statement like 'select ... where [3 conditions]' about 10k times may slow down my application strongly.
Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: It's hard to answer without any details. You could dump your Excel data in a temporary table and do the import from that temp table.

Comment: What is an *SQL table*? SQL is a language. Please tag and mention the RBDMS. Maybe you meant Oracle table, SQL Server table, Postgres table? SQL solutions vary by these dialects.

Comment: @the_lotus Do You mean I have to import Excel data to server?

Comment: @Parfait obviously I meant a SQL Server table.

Comment: @Raven2946 ... SQL again is a language and Microsoft does not own it. Though MSSQL has SQL in its name we cannot assume you meant this RDBMS. Tag or be specific. As a general-purpose language, VB.Net can connect to practically any relational database.

Comment: Once I used name MS Excel a moderator crossed "MS" off. There are some applications, which are known and don't have to use MS at the beginning. Moreover, your comments doesn't give any help at the main topic and I have strong feeling that You just want to are pick somebody. BRB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are correct in assuming calling a select 10 times from your .net application will take an excessive time.

A faster and much more efficient option is to import your data into a table in your SQL database either using the tools your SQL server offers for import or programmatically using [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx).

Once in your database you can write SQL statements to perform the necessary data operations for your needs:

```
INSERT INTO [DBO].TableName([DestColumm0, DestColumn1,...])
SELECT [SrcColumn1,SourceColum2...] FROM  DBO.[ImportTable] 
WHERE
     SourceColumX = ConditionA AND
     SourceColumY = ConditionB AND
     SourceColumZ = ConditionC
```

NOTE: *[DestColumm0, DestColumn1,...]* and *[SrcColumn1,SourceColum2...]* are place holders for your destination and source column names.

Comment: But there are about 10k different sets of ConditionA, CondtionB, ConditionC. I thought about import Excel data into other table and use INNER JOIN, do You think it will work and will not it overload the server? I am not an owner of the server...

Comment: That's the way to go. Its only 100k records you'll be fine. I deal with 10s to 100s of millions. If you are worried about the server you can Install sql on your own desktop and do the work locally. Get SQL express advanced.

Comment: After you import it just run the select part of the query first. You'll see it runs a lot faster than you realize. If it is slow for some reason create an index on the three columns you are joining on and your query will take milliseconds

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Raven2946 If an answer has helped you, marking it as the correct answer will help others with similar problems :)